# MulePollManager has disappeared from MUnit 1.0.0

Tags: unit-testing, mule, munit

We used the class org.mule.munit.MunitPollManager(in the munit-utils package) in older versions of MUnit to make sure that our poller did not start when the flow started, however this seems to have disappeared when Munit migrated to 1.0.0. How can this be replicated in the new Munit?

Answer (score 1):

the class is still there.

What it may have happen is that with the changes in the project structure you're not getting the dependency anymore.

The class is in the artifact

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>munit-mclient-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score -1):

When testing with `Munit`, aren't Mule `inbound-endpoints` disable by default

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.